# php command line reader

Tags: php, command-line, process, stream, children

So I want to be able to do the following in PHP. From the command line I call a script.

```
 /usr/bin/php mychildren.php
```

I want the script to be able to create 2 child processes both of which stay active indefinitely. (say we make them infinite loops =D), but I want the child processes to occasionally to echo out hello for the 1st process and goodbye for the second process. And then when I do a signal interrupt (ctrl+c) using pcntl_signal I can then kill the 2 child processes and once I have verification that they are killed then I kill the parent process.

Is this even possible?! I looked through streaming a little and I am super confuzzled as to how to get this working. Seems like it should work, but I can't get anything to work properly.

Quick details:
2 child processes
each child processes occasionally echos something random
when I kill the parent the children die, and once they are dead then the parent dies

Comment: You might look into this:  http://php.net/manual/en/refs.fileprocess.process.php  You'll probably want some IPC and what not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While you can use [`pcntl_fork`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pcntl-fork.php) to create subprocesses, oftentimes it is better to execute the subprocesses anew with [`proc_open`](http://php.net/proc_open). Use [`pcntl_signal`](http://php.net/pcntl_signal) to install signal handlers (to kill the subprocesses). If you want the child processes to directly write to the same output, you'll have to implement some kind of IPC to avoid both writing at the same time.

Therefore, it's probably better to let both subprocesses write to the main process, and let the main process wait for full lines or otherwise synchronize outputs.

Comment: How would you let both children write to the main processes? So say for example the child processes are `echo "hello";` How would I grab that echo from the parent process in order to write it? And can I keep echoing them out from the parent even while the child processes are running?

Comment: The easiest way to do so is to call [`proc_open`](http://php.net/proc_open) instead of `fork`, since `proc_open` will transparently handle all the internals for you. If you must use `fork` (for example because of performance reasons, or because you want to access significant parts of the main program and its data in the children), you can create a named pipe with [`posix_mkfifo`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.posix-mkfifo.php). Unfortunately, php does not seem to have a wrapper for [`pipe`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/pipe) right now.

Comment: I ended up using forks mainly cause the whole proc_open concept confuses me. I don't know how to necessarily have the parent wait and be able to control all the processes it opens. Maybe in the future I'll learn to do it. Thanks though!